# How to install mcrypt in dual PHP version CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, centos6, lamp, rpm, php-mcrypt

I have two parallel versions of PHP installed on CentOS 6.5 via this [method](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp)

```
[root@host ~]# php -i | grep "PHP Version"
PHP Version => 5.3.3
[root@host ~]# /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php -i | grep "PHP Version"
PHP Version => 5.4.16
```

The installs came from

```
[root@host ~]# rpm -q php php-mcrypt
php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.1.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
[root@host ~]# rpm -q php54 php54-mcrypt
php54-1-7.el6.centos.alt.x86_64
package php54-mcrypt is not installed
[root@host ~]# rpm -q libmcrypt
libmcrypt-2.5.8-4.el6.art.x86_64
[root@host ~]# rpm -q libmcrypt-devel
libmcrypt-devel-2.5.8-4.el6.art.x86_64
```

On sites running PHP 5.3.3, mcrypt works fine. I need to make mcrypt available to the sites running 5.4.16. Naturally I tried `yum install php54-mcrypt`, but that returns `No package php54-mcrypt available.`. The following repos are enabled:

```
asl-4.0 
base 
epel 
extras 
scl 
updates 
virtualmin 
virtualmin-universal
```

So I searched for an RPM, and found [this one](http://rpms.southbridge.ru/rhel6/php-5.4/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.4.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm). But if I try to install this RPM, it tries to update the currrent PHP mcrypt, which I need to keep running for sites on 5.3.3. I'm under the impression that php-mcrypt needs to be an exact to the php version and it's not backwards compatible.

**I need to install mcrypt for PHP 5.4.16, where PHPZTS="" and PHPAPI=20100525. How can I do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [rpm2cpio](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html) to convert the only suitable [.rpm](http://rpms.southbridge.ru/rhel6/php-5.4/x86_64/php-mcrypt-5.4.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm) file I found into a cpio archive on standard out.

```
$ rpm2cpio php-mcrypt-5.4.16-1.el6.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

I then copied mcrypt.so an mcrypt.ini to the proper folders for the PHP 5.4 install.

Voilá, mcrypt works now!

Comment: This worked for me, the problem afterwards is glibc-2.14 was required and although I tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/sysconfig/httpd and /etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd, it seems Apache 2.2 hung, so I gave up with php54 in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the CentOS SCL collection for php54 does not include php54-mcrypt.

You can take the SRPM for the php-mcrypt-5.4 and modify the spec to change the package name, install location, etc. In other others, create your own package (check `rpmbuild`).

Or you could also use [rcollet](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2013/08/01/php-5-4-on-rhel-6-using-rhscl/)'s repository as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @gtirloni, but I found a more practical solution.

Comment: Glad it worked! Just remember to keep it updated, as it sits outside your package management system now.